# Checking range of List in forEach lambda loop Java 8

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8

I want to learn how I can check the range of a list in java 8.

For example,

My Code:

```
    List<String> objList = new ArrayList<>();
    objList.add("Peter");
    objList.add("James");
    objList.add("Bart");

    objList.stream().map((s) -> s + ",").forEach(System.out::print);
```

My out come is

```
    Peter,James,Bart,
```

but I want to know how I can get rid of the last ,

Note: I know I must use filter here , yet I do not know how and I know there is another way to solve this which is as follows

```
String result = objList.stream()
    .map(Person::getFirstName)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

**yet I want to know how to check the range and get rid of , in my first code.**

Comment: for love of God, when you vote it down, please say why? what is wrong with this question?

Comment: ... what? Are you confused of sorts?

Comment: no for example in imperative style it is clear how to check the range but here I do not know. I just want to get rid of the last comma

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no direct way to get the index of a stream item while you're processing the items themselves. There are several alternatives, though.

One way is to run the stream over the indexes and then get the elements from the list. For each element index it maps `i` to the i'th element and appends a "," for all indexes except the last:

```
IntStream.range(0, objList.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> objList.get(i) + (i < objList.size()-1 ? "," : ""))
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

A second, more concise variation is to special case the first element instead of the last one:

```
IntStream.range(0, objList.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> (i > 0 ? "," : "") + objList.get(i))
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

A third way is to use the particular `reduce` operation that is applied "between" each two adjacent elements. The problem with this technique is that it does O(n^2) copying, which will become quite slow for large streams.

```
System.out.println(objList.stream().reduce((a,b) -> a + "," + b).get());
```

A fourth way is to special-case the last element by limiting the stream to length n-1. This requires a separate print statement, which isn't as pretty though:

```
objList.stream()
    .limit(objList.size()-1)
    .map(s -> s + ",")
    .forEach(System.out::print);
System.out.print(objList.get(objList.size()-1));
```

A fifth way is similar to the above, special-casing the first element instead of the last:

```
System.out.print(objList.get(0));
objList.stream()
    .skip(1)
    .map(s -> "," + s)
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Really, though the point of the `joining` collector is to do this ugly and irritating special-casing for you, so you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: I accepted your answer cuz it closer to what I am looking for, but I have a question. How can I have access to first and second elements at the same time during map processs?

Comment: @user3674428 If you're streaming the elements of the list itself, you can't. If you have a list, you can create a stream of indexes using `IntStream.range` and then within a mapper, use `list.get(i)` and `list.get(i+1)`.

Comment: thank you for your response. I get some idea can you check my another post which is related to this and help me to slove this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770637/filter-twice-lambda-java

Comment: it is k but thank you. your answer lead me to that question, so I owe you a big thank you as well. :)

Comment: is there any way I can be in touch with you by email?

Comment: just could you take a look at that question and tell me how can i can make it better if i have 8 elements. basically works for odd number and even number of elements

Comment: @user3674428 Sorry, I already get more email than I can handle. :-) See my comment on Eran's answer to that question.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
objList.stream().flatMap((s) -> Stream.of(s, ','))
        .limit(objList.size() * 2 - 1).forEach(System.out::print);
```

[`flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) replaces each element of the original stream with the elements in the streams returned from the mapping function.

So if your stream was originally

```
"Peter" - "James" - "Bart"
```

The above mapping function changes it to

```
"Peter" - "," - "James" - "," - "Bart" - ","
```

Then the [`limit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) removes the last `","` by shortening the stream to be at most the length of the value that is passed to it, which in this case is the size of the stream - 1. The size of the stream was 2 * the size of the list before `limit` because `flatMap` doubled it's length.

Note that this will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the list is empty, because the value passed to `limit` will be -1. You should check for this first if that is a possibility.

Comment: could you explain flatMap please?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: "Peter", ", could you tell me what is the difference between comma with and without qoutations?

Comment: without quotations is to separate elements, they are not in the stream.

Comment: interesting and how it removes it?

Comment: why mulityply to two ?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
String concat = objList.stream().reduce(",", String::concat);
System.out.println(concat);
```

Comment: thank you for you answer but could you please help me to find a way to solve this with mapping?

Comment: ,PeterJamesBart is out put that I get and it is wrong

Answer (score 1):

We can also try using limit and skip methods of stream API to this problem. Here is my try to this problem.

```
    returnData.stream().limit(returnData.size()-1).forEach(s->System.out.print(s+","));
    returnData.stream().skip(returnData.size()-1).forEach(s->System.out.print(s));
```

returnData is a List of Integers having values 2,4,7,14. The output will look like 2,4,7,14

Comment: `if (returnData.size()>0){ returnData.stream().limit(returnData.size()-1).forEach(s->System.out.print(s+",")); returnData.stream().skip(returnData.size()-1).forEach(s->System.out.print(s));}`

Answer (score 0):

```
objList.stream().filter(s -> { return !s.equals("Bart") })
```

This will reduce the stream to the strings which are NOT equal to Bart

And this will print the last value of a map :

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0, "a");
map.put(1, "c");
map.put(2, "d");

Integer lastIndex = map.keySet().size() - 1;

Stream<String> lastValueStream = map.values().stream().filter(s -> s.equals(map.get(lastIndex)));
```

Comment: how do you know Bart is the last item? I want something genral

Comment: you will have to use a Map if you want to work with exact positions - the keys being numeric and the values being your strings, for example.  The key with the highest value will yield your last map-value.

Comment: would you please through your code in your answer so I can run it?

Comment: i am fairly certain that my tiny example will work as it is .... but since you asked nicely i'll actually use my development-environment at my workplace to test it ... one moment please.

Comment: not your code in answser part. I am talking about your code in comment part

Comment: objList.stream().filter(s -> !s.equals("Bart") ).map((s) ->  s + ",").forEach(System.out::print);
just does not write Bart

Comment: thats not my code. I added your extension to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
int[] counter = new int[]{0};
objList.stream()
    .map(f -> (counter[0]++ > 0? "," : "") + f)
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```