# Filter Twice Lambda Java

Tags: java, dictionary, filter, lambda, java-8

I have a list as follows `"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"`
and 
Expected outcome must be

```
"1 2" "3 4" "5 6" "7"
```

I figure it out how to do till 7

My outcome

```
"1 2" "3 4" "5 6"
```

**I am wondering to know how I can type 7 as well.**

I added  `i -> i == objList.size()-1` to my filter yet it does not give what I want

anybody has any idea how to slove this?
Code:

```
List result = IntStream.range(0, objList.size()-1)
            .filter( i -> i % 2 == 0 || i -> i == objList.size()-1)
            .mapToObj(i -> objList.get(i) + "" + objList.get(i + 1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());      
    result.forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i ));
```

Comment: haha no it is not. what kind of university you know that teaches lambda in java. let me know so I can attend there lol

Comment: looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749146/combining-an-arrays-index-0-with-1-2-with-3-4-with-5/24749198#comment38398524_24749198

Comment: I am just trying to apply lambda in java here. I saw this already :)
do you have any idea how we can fix it with lambda here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first probelm is with `IntStream.range(x,y)`. This method expects a range which is inclusive at the start and exclusive at the end. Since you passed `objList.size()-1` (6 in your case) as the end of the range, the index of the last String in your input list (6) was excluded from the `IntStream` and the String located at this index ("7") didn't appear in your output.

```
static IntStream range(int startInclusive,
                       int endExclusive)

Returns a sequential ordered IntStream from startInclusive (inclusive) to endExclusive (exclusive) by an incremental step of 1.

API Note:

    An equivalent sequence of increasing values can be produced sequentially using a for loop as follows:


         for (int i = startInclusive; i < endExclusive ; i++) { ... }
```

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-))

Change it to `IntStream.range(0, objList.size())`.

Another problem is that `.filter( i -> i % 2 == 0 || i -> i == objList.size()-1)` won't compile, since it expects a single lambda expression, and you don't need the `|| i -> i == objList.size()-1` part anyway (since the last index of the array, 6, is already even).

Of course that still won't work. If you fix those problems `objList.get(i + 1)` will give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception when i = 6.

My fix to the final problem is probably not the most elegant possible solution, but that's the first thing I came up with that compiled and worked at this late hour.

Fixing that we finally get (after some minor formatting added in the last line) :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.List;

public class LambdaTest     
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        List<String> objList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
        List<String> result = IntStream.range(0, objList.size())
            .filter( i -> (i % 2) == 0)
            .mapToObj(i -> (i<objList.size()-1)?(objList.get(i) + " " + objList.get(i + 1)):objList.get(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());      
        result.forEach(i -> System.out.print("\"" + i + "\" "));
    } 
}
```

I tried this code [here](http://www.tryjava8.com/) and got the expected output.

Comment: you desearve to be bowed so i do here for you M(--)M and if I wish I had enough point to give you +1

Comment: just one question to understand it better . could you explain this more? 'This range is inclusive at the start and exclusive at the end. That's why 6 is excluded and you don't get the "7" in your output."

Comment: @user3674428 Your List has 7 Strings, so its size is 7 and since the first index is 0, the last is 6. IntStream(0,6) would return a Stream containing the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5. 6 is excluded since the end of the range is exclusive. That's why you have to pass the size of the List and not size-1.

Comment: is there any way I can be in touch with you by email?

Comment: @user3674428 For what purpose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57363/discussion-between-user3674428-and-eran).

Comment: a question regarding to the question.what should we do if we have 8 elements in the list?

Comment: @user3674428 This answer seems to handle 8 elements just as well as it handles 7 elements. I don't see any obvious way to simplify it. Possibly variations are run the range from 0 to `objList.size()/2` and then doubling it in the appropriate places, instead of filtering out the odd numbers. Or, refactoring the `? :` conditional into a helper method. But these are points of style, not fundamental simplifications.

Comment: when I add for example 8 to the list, it does not behave well. Could you please be kind and run it so you can see? thank you

Comment: @user3674428 Really? That's strange.  I actually tried it today and it worked. I added 8 and it worked, then added 9 which worked too. Please make sure you are running the same code as in the answer.  When I get to my laptop I'll make sure the code in my answer is the same as the code I ran.

Comment: I use netbeans but I will test it up again when I go home and let you know

Comment: @user3674428 I tried the code again (copied and pasted the code from my answer to tryjava8.com) with 7 and 8 elements and it works fine. For 8 elements I get the output `"1 2" "3 4" "5 6" "7 8"`.